# Spring & ActiveMQ Artemis dependencies conflict

Tags: maven, spring-integration, activemq-artemis

I am refactoring my application from Spring 5.x to Spring 6.0.0.

Due to changes in the Java API's imposed by Oracle some dependencies have been forced to be changed.

There appears to be a dependency conflict where the `org.springframework.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer` requires a  `jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory`, but the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` extends the older `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`.

I suspect that there is a POM dependency that I am missing, but I have been unable to resolve it.

**POM excerpt:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-flow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.27.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-spring-integration</artifactId>
    <version>2.27.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code Snip:**

```java
// ActiveMQConnectionFactory implements javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
@Order(0)
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    if (connectionFactory == null) {
        connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        PropertyValue pv = configPropertiesService.fetchPropertyValue(PropertyValueConstants.ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_URL,
                PropertyValueConstants.ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_URL_DEFAULT);
        PropertyValue pvu = configPropertiesService.fetchPropertyValue(PropertyValueConstants.ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_UNAME,
                PropertyValueConstants.ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_USERNAME_DEFAULT);
        PropertyValue pvp = configPropertiesService.fetchPropertyValue(PropertyValueConstants.ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_PASS,
                PropertyValueConstants.ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_PASS_DEFAULT);
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(pv.getValue());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(pvp.getValue());
    }

    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "MessageDrivenAdapter")
public MessageListenerContainer getContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());  // requires jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory
    container.setDestinationName("requestsQueue");
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener());
    container.setAutoStartup(false);
    container.setTaskExecutor(stepTaskExecutor);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(5);

    return container;
}
```

Comment: Spring-integration-flow - it hasn't been updated since 2015, but I haven't finished refactoring the product either. I have roughly 1/2 million lines of code to go, and will get to this when it pops up as the next refactoring in the list.

Comment: changes in the java API's imposed by Oracle: Oracle ended support for several libraries in the javax namespace and donated them to the Eclipse foundation. The eclipse foundation is not allowed to use the javax namespace, so those libraries (unchanged) are now under the jakarta namespace. in this case, the old javax.jms namespace is now jakarta.jms. This forced the Spring API's to change to support the jakarta namespace instead of the javax namespace, and one package appears to have been missed.

Comment: @pojo-guy use `artemis-jakarta-client` instead of `artemis-jms-client`

Comment: @khmarbaise https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/05/end-of-javax-package/

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Turn this into an answer and I will accept it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ developers provide two flavours of their library (seems to be the most sober approach for that messy `javax` -> `jakarta` transition):

- [ActiveMQ Artemis JMS Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-jms-client) - compatible with Java EE API (`javax.` namespace)
- [ActiveMQ Artemis Jakarta Messaging Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-jakarta-client) - compatible with JakartaEE 9 API (`jakarta.` namespace)

You need the second one.